# HurwitzLerchPhi

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I am not sure why this is returned unevaluated:

```
HurwitzLerchPhi[1, 1, ∞]
```

Everything is returned unevaluated

```
HurwitzLerchPhi[-I, 1, ∞]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my explanation. The results of the codes

```
∞ ∈ Reals
```

> `False`

and

```
∞ ∈ Complexes
```

> `False`

prove that `∞` is not a real/complex number, so its substitution in any function makes no sense.
The result of

```
Limit[HurwitzLerchPhi[-1, 1, x], x -> ∞]
```

> `0`

is sometimes written as `HurwitzLerchPhi[-1, 1, ∞]==0`. It should be noticed that such notation may confuse in view of

```
Limit[HurwitzLerchPhi[-1, 1, x], x -> ComplexInfinity, Direction -> Complexes]
```

> `Indeterminate`

Comment: BTW, the example `Exp[\[Infinity]]==\[Infinity]` and related examples from the documentation to `\[Infinity]`  do not make a good impression about mathematical culture of the developers.